# Autoplay background music not working. Included mute button also

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I added background music to my site and the initial plan was that the music would start automatically. I also added a mute button to the page because some people may find it annoying.

I used font awesome to make the mute button.

Everything worked fine with the mute button, but there's this problem in Google Chrome where it won't autoplay music if you didn't interact with the site.

I've tried to put an iframe and then link the music, but I guess you can't actually mute an iframe in JavaScript or jQuery?

Can someone please help me?
Thanks

```
<audio id="audio" autoplay hidden loop>
  <source src="music/backgroundMusic.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<i class="fas" id="mute"></i>

$("#mute").toggleClass("fa-volume-up");

$("#mute").click(function() {
    var bool = $("#audio").prop("muted");
    $("#audio").prop("muted",!bool);
    $("#mute").toggleClass("fa-volume-up");
    $("#mute").toggleClass("fa-volume-mute");
});
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: I don't get any error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be changed. Browsers introduced that because people were, well, autoplaying sound without a user consent. That being said, there are options.

Possible workaround, and this is what we used in one of projects I worked on, is to attach play option to some first action. This could be something like that:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // here "autoplay" starts
}, { once: true });
```

Thanks to `once` it will unsubscribe after first run. In our project we were using click event on some other event (like welcome message that needed to be closed before playing) and maybe you can use this.

So, to summarize, you will need to conceal the action in some smarter way.

---

`once` option documentation can be found here: [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)